# how to unpack a tuple in this form ('abc', [20, 20])?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I want this to be unpacked in two variable for examaple.
something like..

```
a,*b = ('abc', [20,20])
```

i want a to contain 'abc' and b to hold the list [20,20].

Comment: Did you try it without the `*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
a,b = 'abc', [20,20]
```

If you removed the asterix, your code would have worked

Comment: Your solution is correct, but you've changed OP's input. N.B. I am not downvoter.

Comment: No, the input didn't change. It's the comma that defines a tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: The inut _did_ change, specially if you don't explain the full tuple syntax and the optional nature of the parenthesis in the body.

Answer (score -1):

`a, b = ('abc', [20,20])`

It is that simple. Afterwards:

- a is 'abc'
- b is [20,20]

Comment: I would not have written "It is that simple", but answers have aminimm charatcer limit. And this one was bellow it - overall -  the idea of "simplicity" is not attacking the question or your need for it - but that it is simple to do after you know about it.

Comment: i misunderstood your statement....thanks for the solution.